# Deleting closed posts on meta?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

What's the meta formalities over deleting meta posts with answers that are closed as being off topic? Is it ok to delete them?

Comment: You mean for questions that won't ever roomba, right?

Comment: @rene yes correct.

Comment: I dislike the trend towards deleting the _can no longer be reproduced_ questions that are part of a sites's history (rather than _"I've got some malware"_ kind).

Comment: Is this question about users voting to delete posts or a moderator deleting a post? (seeing you tagged it with vote-to-delete) Or just generally about deleting posts?

Comment: @AndréKool general community, and as such the mods would follow the community consensus. I'm reluctant to cast a binding vote, unless it's clear that's what the community wants.

Comment: I think it's 200% okay to instantly remove blatantly off-topic requests for coding help, like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367744/paramiko-ssh-failing-to-execute-the-command)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools, that according to me applies well also on meta.

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.

**Conclusion**: no lasting value, no good answers.

---

If you are a moderator you should also consider that you have single vote power and that you are not in a situation of "conflict-of-interests", if so I would advise you to speak to your fellow moderators.

Comment: perfect answer. This is what I was also thinking. Yes having mod votes, makes me more reluctant to delete meta content.

Comment: That's perfect, let the >10K  do the job, if it's not some rude stuff that needs quick removal. Also for your own question that have not been appreciated by community just leave'em if you have some good answer (appreciated by community or you) on them. You may have changed your mind reading some of the answer, well then after all it was a good question!

Comment: Now, if 10kers would use their votes more...

Comment: @pnuts my comment was actually aimed to votes on main. BTW, there are 13k users with 10k on main. That means 39k questions that could be deleted even when all of them needs the maximum amount of votes required (10), if we are talking about the common case (3 votes), there are 130k possible questions that can be deleted in a single day. TL;dr: 10kers do not vote to delete enough.

Comment: Let's keep in mind Ben's point from the comments on the question about _historical_ value. Many questions about Documentation were closed when it was shut down, for instance, but shouldn't be deleted because they are part of the historical record about the evolution of the site.

Comment: The [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) on SO says that: *Vandalizing or excessive deletion of useful posts may trigger an alert within the system, and prompt action from the moderation team.* Does this apply to Meta too?

Comment: @Yatin, no clue but that's also related to own question that you are able to delete (no upvoted answers), I'm not sure we have users that are able to self delete questions on meta to trigger that.. you need to post crap, get it down voted, delete it (before others do).. if so I hope it triggers some flag and even if not I guess moderators will notice and hunt you down.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Petter said, deletion exists to **reduce noise**. Sometimes a question isn't just bad, it's noisy as well. So [asking if SO needs an "experts only" area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356539/lets-set-up-an-experts-area-at-stack-overflow)(10k+ link) probably shouldn't hang around long, since it's contentious and unproductive.

Meta needs a bit more discretion, in that sometimes people [make mistakes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274959/2370483) (10k link) and we need to leave them up so [others learn from them](https://despair.com/collections/demotivators/products/mistakes?variant=2457302467)

Comment: How do you still have that deleted question link with you?

Comment: Browser history